# Collections.sort one list share the index another list

Tags: android, sorting

I have ArrayList items
NewItems bean class has  int starCount  property

And I have another ArrayList keys

I want to sort NewItems and keys together.
first items change indices
second key share indices.

i used the comperator

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<ItemTruckDes>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Items o1, Items o2) {
                        return o1.starCount < o2.starCount ? 1 : o1.starCount > o2.starCount ? -1 : 0;
                    }
                });
```

And It will Add the sorting the Keys List

example

```
  items.get(0).starCount = 3   keys.get(0) = “as”
  items.get(1).starCount = 5   keys.get(1) = “bh”
```

I will sort by

```
  items.starCount ( descending)
```

then it will be that

```
 items.(0) = 5  items.get(1)= 3
```

And I want to change the keys index

then

```
    keys(0)= “bh” 
    keys(1) = “as”
```

I found the many sample about that,
but it now worked for me.

i don't know how to sync index prikeys And items

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please post an [example of what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you with specific problems

Comment: But I never know that;;